# Facebook login does not pass session login parameters during the first login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

Facebook login does not pass the session parameters during the first login mostly on chromium based browsers. However from the second login it works and it passes the session parameters. Due to this behaviour the images do not get displayed during the first login.

Please find below a screen recording of the issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hig44sBeRsQq0rgr7imjOcsblfmedUuh/view?usp=sharing

The code snippet of the implementation:

```php
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
require_once './Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
#$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  print 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  print 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    print "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    print "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    print "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    print "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    print 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
print '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
print '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException s when they fail)
#$tokenMetadata->validateAppId(''); 
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('');// Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();




try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,gender,picture,timezone', $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  print 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  print 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
$user1 = $response->getGraphUser();
$user2 = $response->getGraphUser();
$user3 = $response->getGraphUser();
$user4 = $response->getGraphUser();
print 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
$user = $user['name'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $user;
print $user;
print 'Email: ' . $user1['email'];
$_SESSION['emailfb'] = $user1['email'];
#print 'Location: ' . $user2['location'];
#$_SESSION['location'] = $user2['location'];
print 'Picture: ' . $user3['picture'];
$_SESSION['picturefb'] = $user3['picture'];
//profile pic
print"profile picture";
print"<br>";
$fbp = $_SESSION['picturefb'];
print"<br>";
#print"id:";
print 'id: '. $user1['id'];
$_SESSION['idfb'] = $user1['id'];
$id = $_SESSION['idfb'];
#$_SESSION['fbid'] = 

$imgurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=720';

$_SESSION['imgurl'] = $imgurl;

print"$imgurl";

print"<br>";
print"<img src ='$imgurl'/>";

#print 'Timezone: ' . $user1['timezone'];

// $_SESSION["Gender"] = $user2['location'];

// if(empty($_SESSION["gender"]))
// {
//   $_SESSION["Gender"] ="Details not public";
// }
// print $_SESSION["Gender"];
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['fbflag'] = 1;
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    print "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }
  print '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}


$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
header('Location: https://www.gangabiz.com/9.php');
```

I initially posted it as a bug to Facebook, however Xoe from Facebook bug support asked me to raise this issue with the community as they do not support php issues. Facebook closed the php bug mentioning the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because chromium-based browsers cannot understand that example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) are the same in this case gangabiz.com and [www.gangabiz.com](http://www.gangabiz.com) A htaccess redirect enforcing www solved the problem.